# Change of Variables formula but from small space to large space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z})$ be a measurable space and $\mu$ a probability measure on it. Let $f:\mathsf{Z}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable function and let $\psi:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an invertible mapping (potentially a diffeomorphism, but for now let's assume measurable and invertible).

> Can I claim that the following variant of the change of variables formula applies?
> $$
> \int_{\mathsf{Z}} f\circ \Phi \, d\mu = \int_{\mathsf{Z}^2} f \, d\mu^\Phi
> $$
> where $\Phi:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathsf{Z}^2$ with $\Phi(z) = (z, \psi(z))$

## Background

I am aware of the usual change of variables formula where one has
$$
\int_{\mathsf{Z}} h \circ g \, d\mu = \int_{\mathsf{Z}} h\, d\mu^g
$$
for $h:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathsf{Z}\to\mathsf{Z}$ measurable. However this is a change of variables in the same space, whereas I am interested in a larger space.

Comment: For reference, I am aware the pushforward is a bit weird. Here $\mu$ is a distribution on $(\mathsf{Z}, \mathcal{Z})$ meaning that it assigns a measure to sets $\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{Z}$. Technically, the pushforward is defined as 
$\mu^{\Phi} := \mu \circ \Phi^{-1}$. In this case, $\Phi^{-1}:\mathsf{Z}^2\to\mathsf{Z}$ is somehow defined "only on the diagonal", if it makes sense. Meaning that $\Phi(z, \psi(z)) = z$ but it is not defined for $(z, z')$ where $z' \neq \psi(z)$.